# Кракозябры в TextView - Android Studio

Tags: android, кодировка, android-studio

Android Studio
У элемента ImageButton есть событие OnClick.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView tvHello;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvHello = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.hello_kitty);
}

public void onClick(View v){
    tvHello.setText("Привет, Китти!");
    Log.i("onClick", "BEGIN");

    Log.i("onClick", "END");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Простое тестовое приложение.
Запускаю в эмуляторе.
Нажимаю кнопку, TextView выводит кракозябры вместо кириллицы.
Да, можно через ресурсы вывести текст, но как быть в таком случае? Есть простой выход?

Comment: Решение проблемы на англоязычном сервисе [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677855/android-studio-unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf-8).

Answer (score 7):

кодировку файла класса смените :) 
И да, такие проблемы НУЖНО решать выносом строк в ресурсы

В правом нижнем углу окна
[image]

Comment: Странно, но я изначально ничего не менял. Я обращал внимание часто, что все файлы именно в UTF-8
и этот файл (MainActivity.java) тоже, вот снимок http://f3.s.qip.ru/adNBVlSN.png

Посмотрел несколько файлов проекта, все в UTF-8.

Comment: Значит надо выносить в ресурсы :)
Не стоит зацикливаться на этом.

Comment: прочитал ваш ответ. решение помогло,спасибо. подскажите пожалуйста,что подразумевается под "выносом строк в ресурсы"?

Comment: вот это http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/resources.php