# Запуск метода main() класса без компиляции всего проекта в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Возможно ли в Android Studio запустить метод `main()` простого java-класса, содержащего в себе только ссылки на стандартные классы java, не компилируя весь Android-проект.

Comment: Правой кнопкой мыши по классу – «Run ClassName.main()» не подойдет?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста суть вопроса. Вам необходимо просто выполнить метод `main` как сказали выше и выполнить его на лету в самом Android приложении?

Comment: @post_zeew Весь проект компилируется.

Comment: @Streletz Хочется быстро потестить независимый от Android java-класс.

Comment: В таком случае Android Studio, ИМХО, явно не лучшее решение. Всё-таки эта IDE предназначена для определённого узкого спектра задач. Лучше возьмите какую-нибудь лёгкую IDE общего назначения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно. Для этого нужно указать в IDE, а точней дать новые настройки для вашего дебагера, чтоб он понимал какую часть компилить. В действительности все намного проще.

### Создаем java класс:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Пишем метод main

Все как обычно, IDE сразу распознает точку старта.

```
public class HelloFromMainJava {
    public static void main(String... args){
        System.out.println("HelloFromAndroidStudio ☺!");
    }
}
```

Запустить можно с панели, или right-click мышки, или просто сочетанием клавиш как на скрине.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Итог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не забывайте на панели, сверху, переключать обратно на ваш проект. Удачи.

Comment: Спасибо. Странно, вчера я делала как будто то же самое, а System.out.println ничего не выдавал и компилился весь проект. Сейчас же с Вашей легкой руки все заработало))

Comment: А разве в данном случае компилируется не весь проект?

Comment: В данном случае gradle перелопатит все по стандарту, если вы хотите полностью проигнорить другие классы, то необходимо перенастроить build gradle, как я помню можно точно path в srcSet задать. На самом деле, есть множество вариантов и здесь, будет зависеть от вашего желания. Я по своему опыту открываю отдельно IntelliJ IDEA, так по простому быстрей и удобней и все доп утилиты, которые возможно даже не буду использовать в проекте, пишу и тестирую там. Можно сделать отдельный модуль кстати, если нужны именно Android классы, тоже интересный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Для редактирования и компиляции стандартных Java классов скачайте среду разработки, например, [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/). Удобно и быстро.

Comment: Я уже запускала интересующий меня класс в Intellij Idea. Проблема была в методе toString(). Внутри Android-проекта при использовании этого класса, кириллица выглядела неузнаваемо. При запуске же в Idea кириллические символы выглядели корректно. Пока не выяснились причины этой проблемы.

Comment: @iramm, видел Ваш другой топик, по поводу апдейта SDK и сопутствующими проблемами с кириллицей. Попробуйте сделать как сказано [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/239681/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-textview-android-studio) и [тут](http://mixanix.livejournal.com/10466.html). И, конечно, лучше не использовать кириллицу в коде, а выносить в string.xml, в дальнейшем и заменить/поправить быстрее и локализацию сделать.

Comment: Я бы не против все включить в string.xml, но разве это возможно для сообщений вида "Завтра, 2 октября 2016 года ..." То, что советуете, попробую в ближайшее время.

Comment: @iramm Вам нужно вставить в строковый ресурс переменную? Что то [вроде такого](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5854647)

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо за ссылку. Похоже, я не права. И в этом случае также можно обойтись строковыми ресурсами.

Comment: @Pollux Тут меня убедили, что и правда можно обойтись только строковыми ресурсами.

Comment: @iramm Более того, можно даже использовать [склонение в числительных](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3656409). 1 минута, 5 минут и тп.