# maven компиляция jar

Tags: java, maven

Здравствуйте.Имеется java код вроде как по защите от декомпиляции [indyprotectordemo](https://github.com/licel/indyprotectordemo)
Создал jar через marven

```
mvn compile
mvn packade
```

Запускаю

```
cmd -> java -jar IndyProtectorDemo-1.0.jar test.java test2.java
```

создается test2.java только пустой.
В cmd имею ошибку

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javaone2015.con7442.indyprotector.Demo.main(Demo.java:48)
```

Ошибка происходит из-за

```
InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(args[0]))
```

Гуглил решения так и не нашел.
Пробовал sdk 1.8 и 1.7 а так же разные библиотеки asm.Но ошибки не исчезают и на выходе получаю пустой класс.Кто подскажет в чем проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: покажите весь код, и что у вас делает asm? рискну предположить что на вход он получает  скомпилированные классы с расширением *.class

Comment: Выше по ссылки на гитхабе ссылки на код.Он получает не скомпилированные классы.

Comment: откуда такая уверенность по поводу того что asm принимает не скомпилированный файл?

Comment: Я же его создал в нотепад и положил рядом

Comment: Вот он public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}

Comment: ClassReader принимает поток байтов, содержимое откомпилированного класса, следовательно вам в качестве параметров нужно передавать путь до файла *.class

Comment: Т.е. его нужно еще и спомпилировать?

Comment: да, нужно скомпилировать файл а потом передать его asm

Answer (score 1):

`ClassReader` из библиотеки `asm` принимает на вход поток байтов, содержимого **откомпилированного класса**.

Следовательно, вам нужно передать в качестве аргументов пути до файлов с расширением `*.class`

Можно доработать вашу программу, сделав компиляцию во время выполнения. Будет это выглядеть так:

```
JavaCompiler javac = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
String fileName = arg[0];
javac.run(null, null, null, fileName);

fileName = fileName.replace(".java", ".class");
try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(fileName));
     OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(args[1]))) {

        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(in);
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);
        ClassProtector cp = new ClassProtector(cw);
        cr.accept(cp, 0);
        out.write(cw.toByteArray());
 }
```

Comment: Передаю так C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\indyprotectordemo-master\target\test.java

Comment: test.java скомпилируейте, получите test.class. вот этот файл и нужно будет передать

Comment: Через javac спомпилировал передал и test2.class получаю 0 размера.Почему?

Comment: Привел пример, должно работать.

Comment: Это не моя программа а с jug.Была бы моя сам бы сделал.Взял свой класс из android программы.javac выводит кучу ошибок.Я так понимаю я это без толку затеял?

Comment: в качестве класса который вы подаете на вход, передайте следующее Solution.java:  public class Solution{}. и попробуйте запустите с параметром Solution.java Solution.class при этом внесите изменения в программу, те что я привел выше. У вас должно получиться - не нужно отчаиваться

Comment: На выходе то получаю класс.Открываю его в javadecompiler и получаю // INTERNAL ERROR //.Хотя бы никакая защита работает.Но классы написанные для андроид в android strudio javac не помпилирует.Вот и вопрос в чем.Может это решение не подходит для андроид?

Comment: Ошибка error: package MainActivity does not exist

Comment: Ну естественно. Классы для андройд имеют другие зависимости. Т.е. в стандартной библиотеке java нет класса MainActivity. Он есть только в андройде. следовательно, компилировать их нужно андройд компилятором либо в CLASS_PATH указать путь до системных классов андройд. но не факт что это заработает.

Comment: Т.е. этот код не переделать под андроид

Comment: Можно извернуться и как то его к градлу зафигачить, но зачем? Насколько мне известно в андройде есть свои обфускаторы.

Comment: Этот вроде скрывает вызовы методов.Вот нашел http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572388/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-main-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-android-studio как в андроид скомпилировать один класс.Только что то у меня только есть app и edit configuration.edit configuration не смог настроить.Не знаете как?