# После обновления Android SDK появились проблемы с кириллицей

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Обновила SDK (с 23 до 24). Те русские строки, которые не из xml, стали краказябами, хотя до изменений все было нормально.

Вот как выглядел build.gradle(module:app) до обновления:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mypackage"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']         } }
   }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'}
```

Вот как он выглядит после обновления:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mypackage"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']     } }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
   }
```

Как добиться нормальных букв без отката к старому SDK и без включения всех строк в xml?

Answer (score 1):

Помогло удаление из build.gradle всякого упоминания о java. То есть удалила раздел  `compileOptions` и подраздел `jackOptions`. Теперь как и раньше - никаких "кракозяб".

Правда, судя по всему, будет невозможно пользоваться возможностями java 8. Может, кто-то предложит вариант лучше?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте способы, которые предложены [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/239681/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-textview-android-studio), [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677855/android-studio-unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf-8) и [тут](http://mixanix.livejournal.com/10466.html). И, конечно, лучше не использовать кириллицу в коде, а выносить в string.xml, в дальнейшем и заменить/поправить быстрее и локализацию сделать.

Comment: К сожалению ничего не помогло.